# XCODE Base SDK missing

Tags: iphone, xcode

The only option I am able to see in my Base SDK is IOS 4.2 but I can see all SDK versions in IOS Deployment Target. I am trying to run a project which was written using IOS 3.2 do able to run the current XCODE settings.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have anything incompatible between the iOS 3 and iOS 4 APIs, you should be able to compile and run successfully by changing the Base SDK setting on Project - Edit Project settings (Build tab), and Edit Active Target. Those are the two places that make reference to the original SDK you used (3.2), and the two places you should change to reflect your current SDK (4.2).

Answer (score 1):

yes, change base SDK to "latest iOS" or one which is available with your XCode installation; that should work.

deployment target is the OS version on which the app should be able to run, base SDK is the version you compile and test the app with.

Comment: I did so... Like I choose my Base SDK as 4.2 and my Deployment Target to 3.2 but I am getting lot of errors of the type _OBJC_CLASS_$_<MyClassName> in <MyClassName>.o symbol not found. Please help.